# Form Submission send other element attributes?

Tags: php, jquery, forms, attributes, submission

On form submission does anything else get submitted but the value? Can I submit the value and the data-group attribute?

```
 <input type="text" id="theInput" data-group="5" value="the value" />
```

I'm just talking about a PHP form submission

Comment: You can either create some hidden inputs (input type="hidden"), as their values will be sent, or use JS; don't see the other way around.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only the value gets submitted, but you can add a hidden element for the data-group value. Also note that you should use a `name` attribute to identify the parameter key:

```
<input type="text" id="theInput" name="theInput" data-group="5" value="the value" />
<input type="hidden" name="theInputGroup" value="5" />
```

This will come back to the server with the request parameters of:

- `theInput` ⇒ `the value`
- `theInputGroup` ⇒ `5`

*Sidenote: If you are submitting the form via ajax, you can just add the group directly into the parameter list instead of adding a hidden input.*

Comment: I can't find mention of a `data-group` property on the web. Where is it documented? (Sorry Ben, not you - it appears in the question)

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot, `data-group` is a custom HTML5-standard `data-*` attribute. See http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/

Comment: That's what I had thought but wanted to know if HTML5 other options might be available